# Xcode UIView being resized randomly

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiview

I am developing a game for iPhones, and am having trouble with a levels screen that I am generating dynamically. I have a scrollview that contains a bunch of level pack buttons, which gets added to my view controller's main view. I make the scrollview the width of the screen, and everything is fine and dandy.

When I run the app everything works perfectly. However, after anywhere from 1-30 seconds, the scrollview will magically decide to halve its width, and I have absolutely no idea why.

I have tried overriding `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and hardcoding the width there, but that doesn't work. Also, when I run the app, I do literally nothing to it. I don't even touch the phone itself, and the scrollview will change size, so I have no idea what could even be triggering the scrollview to change size in the first place.

Has anyone even heard of or had this bug before? If so, do you know how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using autolayout constraints? and when I mean using them, are you going all out hard core on using them? If so, I've had this issue and solved it, but I need to know if/how you are constraining the scrollview

Comment: I am generating everything programmatically. The only thing I use storyboard for is the segues.

Comment: perfect, like a boss you are hooking up programatic views, high five through the internet, anyway, read this first and see if it helps:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html  I'm telling you to use this first because my way my or may not work for you and it's easier for you to rule out what you can and can't do first given Apple's broken UIScrollView. UIScrollView is barely usable when you do complex views programming with autolayout or hybrid autolayout. If that doesn't work, I'll show you how I can recreate the problem, implement apple's fix vs my own fix

Comment: Also, one more tip, the "content view" that Apple talks about, you can add UI elements to this content view and constrain them as you would normally. This content view doesn't need to be set to translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = FALSE;, you just leave it at it's default value, add the content view as a subview of the UIScrollView, and then add your elements to the content view, and THEN add constraints to the content View. The subviews of the content view SHOULD be set to "translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false"

Comment: @Larcerax So then based on the tech note you provided, I should just put everything into one view and then put that single view into the scrollview?

Comment: Yep, ill show you a sample, one sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's the declaration:

this has custom fonts, so just ignore custom fonts, it also has custom resizing macros that flex to all iphone sizes, and custom colors, just ignore those as well:

```
_scrollPlaceholder = [UIScrollView new];
[_scrollPlaceholder setDelegate:self];
[_scrollPlaceholder setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:FALSE];
[_scrollPlaceholder setPagingEnabled:false];
[_scrollPlaceholder setBackgroundColor:NSHMasterLightBlueColor];
[_scrollPlaceholder setFrame:CGRectMake(0, heightResizer(50)+heightForNSHNavBar, SCREEN_WIDTH, heightResizer(50))];
[_scrollPlaceholder setContentSize:CGSizeMake(SCREEN_WIDTH*3, heightResizer(50))];
[_scrollPlaceholder setScrollEnabled:true];
[_scrollPlaceholder setKeyboardDismissMode:UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeInteractive || UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeOnDrag];
[_scrollPlaceholder setBounces:false];
[_scrollPlaceholder setDirectionalLockEnabled:true];
[self addSubview:_scrollPlaceholder];

UIView *contentView;
contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,SCREEN_WIDTH*2.2, heightResizer(50))];
[_scrollPlaceholder addSubview:contentView];
[_scrollPlaceholder setContentSize:CGSizeMake(SCREEN_WIDTH*2.2, heightResizer(50))];
```

Here's the contraints:

```
NSDictionary * views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_searchOption1, _searchOption2, _searchOption3, _searchOption4, _searchOption6, _searchOption7, sp1, sp2, sp3,sp4,sp6,sp7,sp8);
NSDictionary * metrics = @{@"sp" : @10, @"spd" : @(heightResizer(40)), @"this" : @(widthResizer(157.0))};

[contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[sp1(>=0)]-[_searchOption1]-[sp2(==sp1)]-[_searchOption2]-[sp3(==sp1)]-[_searchOption3]-[sp4(==sp1)]-[_searchOption4]-[sp6(==sp1)]-[_searchOption6]-[sp7(==sp1)]-[_searchOption7]-[sp8(==sp1)]-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
[contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_searchOption1(spd)]" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
[contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_searchOption2(spd)]" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
[contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_searchOption3(spd)]" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
[contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_searchOption4(spd)]" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
[contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_searchOption6(spd)]" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
[contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_searchOption7(spd)]" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
```

You see, the content view is the same size as the scrollView's content view, the sweetspot here are the macro resizers that make the srollview flex in autolayout even though you basicaly declare the height and width and vertical and height contraints as constants.

Macros, for good measure:

```
#define SCREEN_WIDTH ((([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) || ([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)) ? [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width : [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)

#define SCREEN_HEIGHT ((([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) || ([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)) ? [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height : [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width)

#define hi(n) n/736.00 //<=== set to largest iphone screen height = iphone 6+
#define his(n) n/414.00 //<=== set to largest iphone screen width = iphone 6+

#define heightResizer(n) hi(n)*SCREEN_HEIGHT
#define widthResizer(n) his(n)*SCREEN_WIDTH
```

Also, another thing, there's no need to fiddle around with layout subviews or anything like that, you can declare and set all of this up in ViewDidLoad or in a subclass's default initializer, you don't really have to think about it that much, you can also animate the constraints set up in the content view.

The other way to do this is if you set up the UIScrollView without the content view then you will have to explicity declare all your horizontal constraints with a hard coded WIDTH value in order for it to never shrink, see the following:

```
_redBackGround = [UIScrollView new];
[_redBackGround setDelegate:self];
[_redBackGround setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:FALSE];
[_redBackGround setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[_redBackGround setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:FALSE];
[_redBackGround setScrollEnabled:true];
[_redBackGround setDirectionalLockEnabled:YES];
[_redBackGround setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT)];
[_redBackGround setKeyboardDismissMode:UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeInteractive || UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeOnDrag];
[self addSubview:_redBackGround];

views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(aboutDivider, notificationsDividier, _emailSettingsControl, _passwordSettingsControl, _phoneNumberSettingsControl, _privacyPolicyLinker, _versionNumber, _systemInfoLinker, _userStatsLinker, _contactUsLinker, _termsOfUserLinker, spacerLine1, spacerLine2, spacerLine3, spacerLine4, spacerLine5, spacerLine6, spacerLine7, spacerLine8, spacerLine9, spacerLine10, spacerLine11, _collectionSettings, _messageSettings, _commentSettings, _likesSettings, spacerLinea11, commentsSettingsLabel, collectionsSettingsLabel, messageSettingsLabel, likeSettingsLabel, _zipCodeControl, _zipCodeControl, _catchyMotoControl, spacerLinea12, spacerLinea13, phoneNumberLabel, passwordLabel, emailLabel,  zipCodeLabel, catchyLabelControl);

metrics = @{@"bi" : @(widthResizer(5.0)), @"bh" : @(widthResizer(15.0)), @"sbh" : @(widthResizer(2.0)), @"aw" : @50, @"ah" : @50, @"sp" : @3, @"spd" : @(widthResizer(15.0)), @"sps" : @Spacer, @"fo": @(heightResizer(44.0)), @"smo": @(widthResizer(88.0)), @"fok": @(heightResizer(44.00)), @"spa" : @(widthResizer(20.0)), @"u" : @(widthResizer(404.0)), @"uss" : @(heightResizer(20.0))};

[_redBackGround addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-bi-[spacerLine1(u)]-bi-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
[_redBackGround addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-bi-[spacerLine2]-bi-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
[_redBackGround addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-bi-[spacerLine3]-bi-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
[_redBackGround addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-bi-[spacerLine4]-bi-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
[_redBackGround addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-bi-[spacerLine5]-bi-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
[_redBackGround addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-bi-[spacerLine6]-bi-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
[_redBackGround addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-bi-[spacerLine7]-bi-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
[_redBackGround addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-bi-[spacerLine8]-bi-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
[_redBackGround addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-bi-[spacerLine9]-bi-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
[_redBackGround addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-bi-[spacerLine10]-bi-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
[_redBackGround addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-bi-[spacerLine11]-bi-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
[_redBackGround addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-bi-[spacerLinea11]-bi-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
[_redBackGround addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-bi-[spacerLinea12]-bi-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
[_redBackGround addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-bi-[spacerLinea13]-bi-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
[_redBackGround addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-spa-[catchyLabelControl]-sbh-[_catchyMotoControl]-sbh-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
[_redBackGround addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-spa-[zipCodeLabel]-sbh-[_zipCodeControl]-sbh-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
[_redBackGround addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-spa-[phoneNumberLabel]-sbh-[_phoneNumberSettingsControl]-sbh-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
[_redBackGround addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-spa-[passwordLabel]-sbh-[_passwordSettingsControl]-sbh-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
[_redBackGround addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-spa-[emailLabel]-sbh-[_emailSettingsControl]-sbh-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
[_redBackGround addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[notificationsDividier]|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
[_redBackGround addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-spa-[likeSettingsLabel][_likesSettings(smo)]-bh-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
[_redBackGround addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-spa-[commentsSettingsLabel][_commentSettings(smo)]-bh-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
[_redBackGround addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-spa-[messageSettingsLabel][_messageSettings(smo)]-bh-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
[_redBackGround addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-spa-[collectionsSettingsLabel][_collectionSettings(smo)]-bh-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
[_redBackGround addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[aboutDivider]|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
[_redBackGround addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_privacyPolicyLinker]-spd-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
[_redBackGround addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_versionNumber]-spd-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
[_redBackGround addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_systemInfoLinker]-spd-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
[_redBackGround addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_userStatsLinker]-spd-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
[_redBackGround addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_contactUsLinker]-spd-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
[_redBackGround addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_termsOfUserLinker]-spd-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
[_redBackGround addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-uss-[_phoneNumberSettingsControl(fok)]-sp-[spacerLine1(sps)]-sp-[_passwordSettingsControl(fok)]-sp-[spacerLine2(sps)]-sp-[_emailSettingsControl(fok)]-sp-[spacerLinea13(sps)]-sp-[_zipCodeControl(fok)]-sp-[spacerLinea12(sps)]-sp-[_catchyMotoControl(fok)]-sp-[notificationsDividier(20)]-sp-[_likesSettings(fo)]-sp-[spacerLine9(sps)]-sp-[_commentSettings(fo)]-sp-[spacerLine10(sps)]-sp-[_messageSettings(fo)]-sp-[spacerLine11(sps)]-sp-[_collectionSettings(fo)]-sp-[aboutDivider(20)]-sp-[_privacyPolicyLinker(fok)]-sp-[spacerLine4(sps)]-sp-[_versionNumber(fok)]-sp-[spacerLine5(sps)]-sp-[_systemInfoLinker(fok)]-sp-[spacerLine6(sps)]-sp-[_userStatsLinker(fok)]-sp-[spacerLine7(sps)]-sp-[_contactUsLinker(fok)]-sp-[spacerLine8(sps)]-sp-[_termsOfUserLinker(fok)]-sp-[spacerLinea11(sps)]-sp-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];

[_redBackGround addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
                               constraintWithItem:passwordLabel
                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                               toItem:_passwordSettingsControl
                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                               multiplier:1
                               constant:0]];

[_redBackGround addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
                               constraintWithItem:emailLabel
                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                               toItem:_emailSettingsControl
                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                               multiplier:1
                               constant:0]];

[_redBackGround addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
                               constraintWithItem:phoneNumberLabel
                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                               toItem:_phoneNumberSettingsControl
                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                               multiplier:1
                               constant:0]];

[_redBackGround addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
                               constraintWithItem:zipCodeLabel
                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                               toItem:_zipCodeControl
                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                               multiplier:1
                               constant:0]];

[_redBackGround addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
                               constraintWithItem:catchyLabelControl
                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                               toItem:_catchyMotoControl
                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                               multiplier:1
                               constant:0]];
```

The above has alot of subviews in it, but the one you really want to look at is this one:

```
[_redBackGround addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-bi-[spacerLine1(u)]-bi-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
```

where I explicitly declare the horizontal width of the scroll view in a constraint and this preserves the entire scrollviews width as long as spacerLine1 is present in it's subview

Also, one more thing, both of the approaches above uses both methods of Apple's technical note, I tend to like the second method better, but the first is necessary for complex animations since the scrollview will then serve as a pallete to the contentView who's subviews can be constrained/updated/animated etc, etc. Also, when I say you don't need to mess around with layoutSubviews, I mean you don't have to use this for the rendering of the scrollView as it stands, but you would obviously still need to call layoutIfNeeded if you plan on animating the constraints of the subviews of the content view.

Comment: Adding everything to a single view and adding just that view to the scrollview didn't work, but thanks for the help.

Comment: On a separate note, where would you recommend going to being learning about constraints? I have no clue how they work or how to implement them programmatically (or even much of what they do for that matter).

Comment: One sec, let me find you a source, they will change your life

Comment: I found a very good tutorial on it, here it is: http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2013/01/31/visual-format-language-for-autolayout/   this one goes into the most detail I've seen so far without the usage of anything but raw constraints. There's two forms of constraints, one uses the "visual format language" and is called by "constraintsWithVisualFormat", and the other one is "constraintWithItem" which uses predefined values for the constraints which are obvious ... "height, width, left, right, centerY and center X, leading, trailing, etc, etc. it's all super spiffy